# Scala 3 constructor inheritance with macros

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3

Every class implementing a trait must declare a constructor that sets trait's fields:

```scala
sealed trait WithPayload:
    def description: String
    def payload1: Int
    def payload2: Long

// All WithPayload's fields have to be listed.
final case class Foo(
    override val payload1: Int,
    override val payload2: Long
) extends WithPayload:
    override def description = "foo"

// All WithPayload's fields have to be listed again.
final case class Bar(
    override val payload1: Int,
    override val payload2: Long
) extends WithPayload:
    override def description = "bar"
```

Is there a way to get rid of repeated constructor declarations with a macro, kinda like

```cpp
#define EXTENDS_WITH_PAYLOAD ( \
    override val payload1: Int, \
    override val payload2: Long \
) extends WithPayload
```

and then:

```scala
final case class Foo EXTENDS_WITH_PAYLOAD:
    override def description = "foo"

final case class Bar EXTENDS_WITH_PAYLOAD:
    override def description = "bar"
```

Comment: What about using [trait parameters](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/other-new-features/trait-parameters.html)?

Comment: With trait parameters, not only you have to declare a constructor argument, but you also need to pass it down to the trait, which is even more duplication: `case class C(field1: Int, field2: Long) extends T(field1, field2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In Scala 2 you could define a [macro annotation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html)

```
import scala.annotation.{StaticAnnotation, compileTimeOnly}
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

@compileTimeOnly("enable macro annotations")
class extendsWithPayload extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro ExtendsWithPayloadMacros.macroTransformImpl
}

object ExtendsWithPayloadMacros {
  def macroTransformImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(annottees: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    annottees match {
      case q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }" :: tail =>
        val parents1 = parents :+ tq"WithPayload"
        val newParams = Seq(q"override val payload1: Int", q"override val payload2: Long")
        val paramss1 = paramss match {
          case Nil => Seq(newParams)
          case params :: paramss1 => (params ++ newParams) :: paramss1
        }
        q"""
          $mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss1) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents1 { $self =>
            ..$stats
          }

          ..$tail
        """
    }
  }
}
```

```
sealed trait WithPayload {
  def description: String
  def payload1: Int
  def payload2: Long
}

@extendsWithPayload
final case class Foo() {
  override def description = "foo"
}

@extendsWithPayload
final case class Bar() {
  override def description = "bar"
}

//final case class Foo extends WithPayload with scala.Product with scala.Serializable {
//    override <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> val payload1: Int = _;
//    override <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> val payload2: Long = _;
//    def <init>(payload1: Int, payload2: Long) = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    };
//    override def description = "foo"
//  };
//  ()
//}
//final case class Bar extends WithPayload with scala.Product with scala.Serializable {
//    override <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> val payload1: Int = _;
//    override <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> val payload2: Long = _;
//    def <init>(payload1: Int, payload2: Long) = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    };
//    override def description = "bar"
//  };
//  ()
//}
```

- In Scala 3 there will appear macro annotations too but new definitions can only be seen inside macro expansion

[Macro Annotations in Scala 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67770927/macro-annotations-in-scala-3) ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75808495/5249621))

[How to generate a class in Dotty with macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473523/how-to-generate-a-class-in-dotty-with-macro) ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59474596/5249621))

[Scala 3 macro to create enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69227772/scala-3-macro-to-create-enum)

[How to generate parameterless constructor at compile time using scala 3 macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75159088/how-to-generate-parameterless-constructor-at-compile-time-using-scala-3-macro)

[What can you do with MacroAnnotaiton that you cannot do with Macros in Scala 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76001221/what-can-you-do-with-macroannotaiton-that-you-cannot-do-with-macros-in-scala-3)

```
scalaVersion := "3.3.0-RC4"
```

```
import scala.annotation.{MacroAnnotation, experimental}
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.quoted.*

/*sealed*/ trait WithPayload:
  def description: String
  def payload1: Int
  def payload2: Long

@experimental
class extendsWithPayload extends MacroAnnotation:
  def transform(using Quotes)(tree: quotes.reflect.Definition): List[quotes.reflect.Definition] =
    import quotes.reflect.*
    tree match
      case ClassDef(className, ctr, parents, self, body) =>
        val res = List(ClassDef.copy(tree)(className, ctr, parents :+ TypeTree.of[WithPayload], self, body))
        println(res.map(_.show))
        res
```

```
@extendsWithPayload @experimental
final case class Foo():
  override def description = "foo" // method description overrides nothing

@extendsWithPayload @experimental
final case class Bar():
  override def description = "bar" // method description overrides nothing

summon[Foo <:< WithPayload] // Cannot prove that Foo <:< WithPayload
val foo = new Foo()
foo: WithPayload // Found: (foo: Foo), Required: WithPayload

//List(@scala.annotation.experimental @Macros.extendsWithPayload final case class Foo() extends Macros.WithPayload {
//  override def hashCode(): scala.Int = scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._hashCode(Foo.this)
//  override def equals(x$0: scala.Any): scala.Boolean = Foo.this.eq(x$0.$asInstanceOf$[java.lang.Object]).||(x$0 match {
//    case x$0: App.Foo @scala.unchecked =>
//      true
//    case _ =>
//      false
//  })
//  override def toString(): java.lang.String = scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._toString(Foo.this)
//  override def canEqual(that: scala.Any): scala.Boolean = that.isInstanceOf[App.Foo @scala.unchecked]
//  override def productArity: scala.Int = 0
//  override def productPrefix: scala.Predef.String = "Foo"
//  override def productElement(n: scala.Int): scala.Any = n match {
//    case _ =>
//      throw new java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException(n.toString())
//  }
//  override def description: java.lang.String = "foo"
//})
//List(@scala.annotation.experimental @Macros.extendsWithPayload final case class Bar() extends Macros.WithPayload {
//  override def hashCode(): scala.Int = scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._hashCode(Bar.this)
//  override def equals(x$0: scala.Any): scala.Boolean = Bar.this.eq(x$0.$asInstanceOf$[java.lang.Object]).||(x$0 match {
//    case x$0: App.Bar @scala.unchecked =>
//      true
//    case _ =>
//      false
//  })
//  override def toString(): java.lang.String = scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._toString(Bar.this)
//  override def canEqual(that: scala.Any): scala.Boolean = that.isInstanceOf[App.Bar @scala.unchecked]
//  override def productArity: scala.Int = 0
//  override def productPrefix: scala.Predef.String = "Bar"
//  override def productElement(n: scala.Int): scala.Any = n match {
//    case _ =>
//      throw new java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException(n.toString())
//  }
//  override def description: java.lang.String = "bar"
//})
```

- For example you can use code generation with [Scalameta](https://scalameta.org/)

[Macro annotation to override toString of Scala function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35338239/macro-annotation-to-override-tostring-of-scala-function) ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59127406/5249621))

[In Java or Scala, is there a way to add a callback to an exception so that when the exception is caught, the callback is invoked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74709820/in-java-or-scala-is-there-a-way-to-add-a-callback-to-an-exception-so-that-when) ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74711839/5249621))

[Scala conditional compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61796570/scala-conditional-compilation)

[How to merge multiple imports in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58562229/how-to-merge-multiple-imports-in-scala)

[Scalac 2.13 compiling large auto generated scala file: Method too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76066871/scalac-2-13-compiling-large-auto-generated-scala-file-method-too-large)

*project/build.sbt*

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalameta" %% "scalameta" % "4.7.7"
)
```

*build.sbt*

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "3.2.2"

lazy val common = project

lazy val before = project
  .dependsOn(common)

lazy val after = project
//.dependsOn(common)
  .settings(
    Compile / unmanagedSourceDirectories += (Compile / sourceManaged).value
  )

lazy val transform = taskKey[Unit]("Transform sources")

transform := {
  val inputDir  = (before / Compile / scalaSource).value
  val outputDir = (after / Compile / sourceManaged).value
  Generator.gen(inputDir, outputDir)
}
```

*project/Generator.scala*

```
import sbt.*

object Generator {
  val ALL: Seq[String] = Seq()

  def isAll(filesToTransform: Seq[String]): Boolean = filesToTransform.isEmpty

  def gen(
           inputDir: File,
           outputDir: File,
           filesToTransform: Seq[String] = ALL,
         ): Unit = {
    val finder: PathFinder = inputDir ** "*.scala"
    val scalametaTransformer = new AnnotationProcessor()

    for (inputFile <- finder.get) yield {
      val inputFileName = inputFile.name
      val inputStr = IO.read(inputFile)
      val transform: String => String =
        if (isAll(filesToTransform) || filesToTransform.contains(inputFileName))
          (scalametaTransformer(_: String))
        else identity
      val outputStr = transform(inputStr)
      val outputFile = outputDir / inputFile.relativeTo(inputDir).get.toString
      IO.write(outputFile, outputStr)
    }
  }
}
```

*project/AnnotationProcessor.scala*

```
import scala.meta.*

class AnnotationProcessor extends TreeTransformer {
  val isExtendsWithPayload: Mod => Boolean = { case mod"@extendsWithPayload" => true; case _ => false }

  override def apply(tree: Tree): Tree = {
    val tree1 = tree match {
      case q"..$mods class $tname[..$tparams] ..$ctorMods (...$paramss) $template" if mods.exists(isExtendsWithPayload) =>
        val mods1 = mods.filterNot(isExtendsWithPayload)
        template match {
          case template"{ ..$earlyStats } with ..$inits { $self => ..$stats }" =>
            val inits1 = inits :+ init"WithPayload"
            val template1 = template"{ ..$earlyStats } with ..$inits1 { $self => ..$stats }"
            val newParams = List(param"override val payload1: Int", param"override val payload2: Long")
            val paramss1: List[Term.ParamClause] = paramss match {
              case Nil => List(newParams)
              case params :: paramss1 => (params ++ newParams) :: paramss1
            }
            q"..$mods1 class $tname[..$tparams] ..$ctorMods (...$paramss1) $template1"
        }
      case _ => tree
    }

    super.apply(tree1)
  }
}
```

*project/StringTransformer.scala*

```
trait StringTransformer {
  def apply(str: String): String
}
```

*project/TreeTransformer.scala*

```
import scala.meta.*

trait TreeTransformer extends Transformer with StringTransformer {
  override def apply(str: String): String = {
    val origTree = dialects.Scala3(str).parse[Source].get
    val newTree  = apply(origTree)
    newTree.toString
  }
}
```

*common/src/main/scala/extendsWithPayload.scala*

```
import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation

class extendsWithPayload extends StaticAnnotation
```

*before/src/main/scala/App.scala*

```
sealed trait WithPayload:
  def description: String
  def payload1: Int
  def payload2: Long

@extendsWithPayload
final case class Foo():
  override def description = "foo"

  @extendsWithPayload
  class Nested():
    override def description = "nested"

@extendsWithPayload
final case class Bar():
  override def description = "bar"

final case class Baz()
```

Execute `sbt after/clean transform`

*after/target/scala-3.2.2/src_managed/main/App.scala*

```
sealed trait WithPayload {
  def description: String
  def payload1: Int
  def payload2: Long
}
final case class Foo(override val payload1: Int, override val payload2: Long) extends WithPayload {
  override def description = "foo"
  class Nested(override val payload1: Int, override val payload2: Long) extends WithPayload { override def description = "nested" }
}
final case class Bar(override val payload1: Int, override val payload2: Long) extends WithPayload { override def description = "bar" }
final case class Baz()
```

- Or you can use C++ preprocessor (`#define`) as you wrote.

[#define in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927107/define-in-java)

```
gcc -xc App.scala -E -P -o App1.scala
```

*App.scala*

```
#define EXTENDS_WITH_PAYLOAD ( \
    override val payload1: Int, \
    override val payload2: Long \
) extends WithPayload

sealed trait WithPayload:
    def description: String
    def payload1: Int
    def payload2: Long

final case class Foo EXTENDS_WITH_PAYLOAD:
    override def description = "foo"

final case class Bar EXTENDS_WITH_PAYLOAD:
    override def description = "bar"
```

*App1.scala*

```
sealed trait WithPayload:
    def description: String
    def payload1: Int
    def payload2: Long
final case class Foo ( override val payload1: Int, override val payload2: Long ) extends WithPayload:
    override def description = "foo"
final case class Bar ( override val payload1: Int, override val payload2: Long ) extends WithPayload:
    override def description = "bar"
```

- Or you can define [Scalafix](https://scalacenter.github.io/scalafix/) re-writing rule.

[Is it possible to using macro to modify the generated code of structural-typing instance invocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62253920/is-it-possible-to-using-macro-to-modify-the-generated-code-of-structural-typing/)

[scala.meta parent of parent of Defn.Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62843979/scala-meta-parent-of-parent-of-defn-object) (Scalameta + Semanticdb)

[Quasiquotes in Scalafix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74506444/quasiquotes-in-scalafix/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I'll probably just continue copy-pasting :)